# Store inputs from few textboxes to one field as array

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to insert text from few textboxes to one field in db?

My table:

[image]

My model class field looks like:

```
public string[] Measurment {get; set;}
```

I want to see in db field something like: "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" or "12345678" or "1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8". It is possible?

How should look controller? Maybe my model field should look diffrent?

Any advices?

ps. in my view this looks like (it is ok?):

```
@for (var i = 1; i <= myvalue; i++)
                        {
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td align="center">@i</td>
                                <td align="center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Measurment)</td>
                                <td align="center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Measurment)</td>
                                <td align="center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Measurment)</td>
                                <td align="center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Measurment)</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use [string.join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) before save.

```
Measurment.Add(textBox1.Text);
Measurment.Add(textBox2.Text);

string finalString = string.Join(",", Measurment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.join method to achieve your requirement. I will suggest to keep them as json will be more manageable.

```
string.Join(",",Measurment)
```